# Invoke HTTP GET and POST request without pages using Node.js + Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, get

I have a Node.js app running with Expressjs. I have the typical setup right now, using view jade files and route js files to process GET and POST requests. An example is as follows:

```
router.post('/postaction', function(req, res) {

    // elements from the actual jade view itself
    var one = req.body.from;
    var two = req.body.to;

    // do something

});

router.get('/getaction', function(req, res) {

    // elements from the actual jade view itself
    var one = req.body.from;
    var two = req.body.to;

    // do something

});
```

This works, I can carry out GET and POST requests. For example, a button might invoke the POST action. My question is, how can I use a separate script or npm module to invoke the same GET and POST requests without having to do it via the views? Ideally, I would have something like this:

```
somescript-get <param1>
somescript-post <param1> <param2>
```

with the params being akin to req.body.from and req.body.to. Essentially, I am looking to emulate the info from the page without having to use the page itself.

I am new to Node.js and would really appreciate some help. Please point out if I haven't explained something enough and I'll try to.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An often-used tool for that is [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/).

For instance, to make a `GET` request:

```
$ curl 'http://your.url/getaction?from=FOO&to=BAR'
```

To make a `POST` request:

```
$ curl -XPOST http://your.url/postaction -d 'from=FOO&to=BAR'
```

An alternative, one that I prefer myself, is [`httpie`](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I resorted to using the npm request module, which is looking promising.

Comment: @intl sorry, perhaps I misunderstood :) I thought you were looking for a standalone script, but if you were looking for a module to perform those requests with, `request` certainly is a good one :)